# ESP8266 wifi module sending data via jQuery

Tags: arduino-ide, wifi, arduino-nano, esp8266

Hey all I have the ESP8266 module and I have already set it up and it's working good. However, when I run this HTML page code here:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ESP8266 LED Control</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="6894" class="led">Toggle Pin 13</button> <!-- button for pin 13 -->

    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".led").click(function(){
                var p = $(this).attr('id'); // get id value (i.e. pin13, pin12, or pin11)

                $.get("http://192.168.9.60:80/", {pin:p}); // execute get request
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have to send the number 6894 instead of 13 because for some reason its not sending out the correct number. If i send 13 then what it receive is 114. When i send 6894 i receive 689.

My arduino code is this:

```
*/
//====================================================================================
//                                [The SSDI of the current wifi router]
//                                |              [The password of the current wifi router]
//                                |              |
//                                V              V
String SSIDandPW    = "AT+CWJAP=\"xxxxxxwifi\",\"xxxxxx123\"\r\n";

//                                      [The STATIC IP of the wifi module]
//                                      |                [The main IP of the router]
//                                      |                |              [The default submask]
//                                      |                |              |
//                                      V                V              V
String eIPrIPmask   = "AT+CIPSTA_DEF=\"192.168.9.60\",\"192.168.9.1\",\"255.255.255.0\"\r\n";
const int ledDimmer = 5;         // Used to dim the LED strip (digital Pin 3)

SoftwareSerial esp8266(9,10);    // Pin D10 to=> TX on ESP8266 | Pin D9 to=> RX on ESP8266
//================================= End define WiFi Module =================================
//==========================================================================================

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT); //Just for a wifi demo from html page

  //================================ Start Setup WiFi Module =================================
  //==========================================================================================
  esp8266.begin(19200);
  sendData("AT+RST\r\n",                    2000, true); // Reset module
  sendData("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n",               2000, true); // Configure as access point
  sendData(SSIDandPW,                       5000, true); // Pass of current wifi
  sendData("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n",               2000, true); // Configure for multiple connections
  sendData("AT+UART_DEF=19200,8,1,0,0\r\n", 2000, true); // Set baud of COM
  sendData(eIPrIPmask,                      2000, true); // Default network mask IP
  sendData("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n",         2000, true); // Turn on server on port 80
  sendData("AT+GMR\r\n",                    2000, true); // Get firmware version
  sendData("AT+CIFSR\r\n",                  2000, true); // Get ip address
  Serial.print("Server is now running!");
  //================================ End Setup WiFi Module ===================================
  //==========================================================================================
}


void loop() {
  //=========================================== Start Loop WiFi Module ===========================================
  //==============================================================================================================
  if(esp8266.available()) {                               // check if the esp is sending a message 
    if(esp8266.find("+IPD,")) {
      delay(500);
      int connectionId = esp8266.read() - 48;             // subtract 48 because the read() function returns

      esp8266.find("pin=");                               // advance cursor to "pin="
      int retunedNum = (esp8266.read() - 48) * 100;       // get first number (example: 123.. this would be "1")
      retunedNum += (esp8266.read() - 48) * 10;           // get second number (example: 123.. this would be "2")
      retunedNum += (esp8266.read() - 48);                // get last number (example: 123.. this would be "3")
      String closeCommand = "AT+CIPCLOSE=";               // make close command
      Serial.print("returned: ");
      Serial.print(retunedNum);
      Serial.print("----------");
      closeCommand += connectionId;                       // append connection id
      closeCommand += "\r\n";     
      sendData(closeCommand,                250, true);   // close connection
      //digitalWrite(retunedNum, !digitalRead(retunedNum));   // toggle pin
      if (retunedNum == 6894) {
        Serial.print("OFF");
        digitalWrite(ledDimmer, LOW);
      } else if (retunedNum == 6904) {
        Serial.print("ON");
        digitalWrite(ledDimmer, HIGH);
      } else if (retunedNum == 689) {
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
        delay(1000);              // wait for a second
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
        delay(1000);              // wait for a second 
      }
    }
  }
  //============================================ End Loop WiFi Module ============================================
  //==============================================================================================================
}

//                     [The data/command to send]
//                     |                  [The time to wait for a response]
//                     |                  |                [Print to Serial window (true = yes | false = no)]
//                     |                  |                |
//                     V                  V                V
String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug) {
  String response = "";
  long int time   = millis();

  esp8266.print(command);          // send the read character to the esp8266

  while((time + timeout) > millis()) {
    while(esp8266.available()) {
                                   // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window
        char c = esp8266.read();   // read the next character.
        response += c;
    }
  }

  if (debug) { Serial.print('Returned: ' + response); }
  return response;
}
```

And the console output is this:

```
14880AT+RST


OK
14880
"qXÑ{ÂB!É
1Â±þ)ÒBÙa
+ò“H!a5)�#)ÒÂia%YakN‘ J!ÐCÊ!�
÷þˆ2ô
ready
14880AT+CWJAP="xxxxxxwifi","xxxxxx123"


OK
14880AT+CIPMUX=1


OK
14880AT+UART_DEF=19200,8,1,0,0


OK
14880AT+CIPSTA_DEF="192.168.9.60","192.168.9.1","255.255.255.0"


OK
14880AT+CIPSERVER=1,80


OK
14880AT+GMR

AT version:0.22.0.0(Mar 20 2015 10:04:26)
SDK version:1.0.0
compile time:Mar 20 2015 11:00:56

OK
14880AT+CIFSR

+CIFSR:STAIP,"192.168.9.60"
+CIFSR:STAMAC,"18:fe:34:9b:4e:68"

OK
Server is now running!

returned: 689----------148804 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.9.60
Connection: AT+CIPCLOSE=0

0,CLOSED

OK
```

What I really am wanting to do is have a way to send a 10 charater string to the arduino instead of the limited 3 numbers above. I just am not sure what i need to add/modify in order to make it see letters/numbers and only the first 10 that i send.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Just do this straight on the ESP8266 no need for an arduino. You should try it as the ESP8266 is not a Wifi add on for arduino but is a controller with wifi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  int retunedNum = (esp8266.read() - 48) * 100;       // get first number (example: 123.. this would be "1")
  retunedNum += (esp8266.read() - 48) * 10;           // get second number (example: 123.. this would be "2")
  retunedNum += (esp8266.read() - 48);                // get last number (example: 123.. this would be "3")
```

Your code always expects the pin number to have 3 digits.

In case of 13, it takes a space character as the last digit.
It reads charachters '1', '3' and ' '. Their ASCII codes are 49, 51 and 32. With this, the calculated number is

```
(49 - 48) * 100 + (51 - 48) * 10 + (32 - 48) = 114.
```

With 6894, it just uses the first three digits and ignores the last.

For 1 or 2 digit long number you could just pad it with '0' character i.g. "013".

If you want to read an arbitrary string, you should replace the above code with this code:

```
String retunedStr = "";
for(;;) {
    char c = esp8266.read();
    if (c == ' ')
        break;
    retunedStr += c;
}
```

And obviously replace

```
Serial.print(retunedNum);
```

with

```
Serial.print(retunedStr);
```

With this, you should only use letters (A-Z, a-z), numbers (0-9), dash (-) and an underscore (_) for the string.
If you use other characters, you could have problems with the URL character encoding.

Comment: This is what i get when sending "testing123".... returned: 0,298:GET

Comment: Actually i take that back. I moved the code to a different part and i do get the correct text from what i sent... but now it takes about **21 seconds** to show up when it used to be once i clicked the button **1 second** latter it was there in the output. If the code looping too much to cause this?